# Generating license keys for my python app

Tags: python, tkinter, license-key, key-generator

this is my first time ever making full python app with tkinter and wanting to distribute it. I've been searching the net, but I cant quite figure out how to make a license key for my application, as in I want a unique key I give to certain people which allows them to run the application, and also I want to able to deactivate that key and make new ones. Note this is an application for window computers, Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: If you want to desactivate remotely, it seems you need a central server that allows the app to run by checking its key everytime it's launched. What is your question ? What have you tried ?

Comment: Generating a key is a piece of cake. Protecting your app especially for an interpreted language is going to be the hard part.

Comment: Yeah I just wanna know how to generate the keys and authenticate it, I have zeroooo clue, I don’t know where to start

Comment: Yeah it seems i need a Server to check it’s key every time  it’s launched

Answer (score 4):

Check out [keygen.sh](https://keygen.sh) - It's LaaS (Licensing as a service).

You create an account and generate license keys with or without an expiration date and number of unique devices. From your app, you then use their API to validate/activate your license.

There's an example showing device activation, license validation and deactivation.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps :)

```py
import requests

def license():
    # The list with all keys.
    keys = requests.get("http://yourlink.com/licensekeys.txt").text
    # keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]

    # License key from user.
    keyfromuser = "mykey"

    for key in keys.splitlines():
        if key == keyfromuser:
            # Code when key match.
            return

    # Code if the key don't match.
    exit()

license()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can generate using python [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) after that need to store in database from there you can authanticate, remove or add new keys.

Comment: Is there a tutorial on this somewhere ?

Comment: I don't know about that but you can make script as I said and If you want gui for this than make django admin panel.

Comment: also one thig you can also implement it like session/coockie so after every X time it'll expire.

Comment: ohk than you can use tkinter but that looks like outdated thing :)
also if you use django than as I think your development will be 20X faster and also looks good.

Comment: Isn’t django used for web application? Mine is desktop application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert it to exe then ship it with an installer, InstallForge app can generate serial codes for you. At the left panel of  InstallForge, there is a Dialog section containing 'Serial Validation.' You can generate random serial codes with it and store it in your activation server.